# adding bin files in android studio

Tags: android, exception, android-studio, bin

I have a bin file **en-parser-chunking.bin** which does the chunking part in my project.I am using it as follows

```
              InputStream modelInParse = null;
              try {
                   //load chunking model
                     Log.i(TAG,"1");
                     modelInParse = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
```

But this is throwing an **IO exception** in android studio.
I have it in my project files as well.

Comment: I am not able to add any file including a text file..

Comment: Help me whats wrong..?

Answer (score 1):

It might be like this

```
InputStream modelInParse = null;
              try {
                   //load chunking model
                     Log.i(TAG,"1");
                     modelInParse = new FileInputStream("Relative/or/absolute/path/of/your/.bin/file");
```

System is unable to locate your file. so it's giving IO Exception. Please give file path properly

Comment: The same exception

04-13 15:50:48.604  21404-21404/com.example.sravankumar.vbnlirs I/HARSHA﹕ 1


04-13 15:50:48.619  21404-21404/com.example.sravankumar.vbnlirs D/HARSHA﹕ [ 04-13 15:50:48.619 21404:21404 I/HARSHA   ]
    Exception

Comment: Generally the main reason for IO Exception is not able to open/ locate specified file. So think again and make corrections accordingly.

Comment: Can bin files be added to android??

Because it was working fine in eclipse..

I wanted to make it an android app, it throws exception..

Comment: You can keep your files in asset folder. and you can use them in your project using AssetManager

Answer (score 1):

- Save your *.bin* file in the `resources` folder (I use a .bin file in my unit tests, so I saved it in `app-name/app/src/test/resources`)
- In your class open the file with `ClassLoader`:

  `public InputStream openBin(String filename) throws IOException {
     lassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
     File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(filename).getPath());
     InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
     return input;
  }`